# Couldn't find module alloy/sync/enc.db when using SQLite Database Encryption Module

Tags: sqlite, encryption, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I tried using the module SQLite Database Encryption Module I downloaded from Appcelerator Platform, which is only available for pro seat.

I added this to my models

```
try {
    require('appcelerator.encrypteddatabase');
    var dbType = "enc.db";
} catch(e) {
    var dbType = "sql";
}
```

And at the adapter

```
adapter : {
            type : dbType,
            collection_name : "somename", 
            idAttribute : "someid",
            migration : "20161105200100"
        }
```

When I run the project I get this error as there is no **enc.db** type for adapter.

Anyone having similar issue while using this module?

EDIT:

Titanium SDK version : 5.5.1.GA
Module version : 1.3.3

Tested on :
iphone 5s, version 10.2.1
simulator iphone 7 plus, version 10.1

Answer (score 0):

To use the platform encrypted module I use:

In `alloy.js`

```
// Use encrypteddatabase if the module is included, else use sql.
try {
    require('appcelerator.encrypteddatabase');
    Alloy.Globals.dbEncrypted = 'enc.db';
} catch (e) {
    console.error('appcelerator.encrypteddatabase module is not available', e);
}
Alloy.Globals.dbType = 'sql';
```

In `models/myModel.js`

```
var dbType = Alloy.Globals.dbEncrypted || Alloy.Globals.dbType || 'sql';

...

config: {
    columns: {
        id: 'TEXT PRIMARY KEY',
        firstName: 'TEXT',
        lastName: 'TEXT'
    },
    adapter: {
        type: dbType,
        collection_name: 'myModel',
        idAttribute: 'id',
        db_name: 'myModel.' + dbType
    }
}
```

The `db_name` is generated specifically for this model in my case (since I have a combination of encrypted and non-encrypted databases but you might as well use something like `db_name: 'myModel'`

Ti SDK Version `5.2.2.GA` and Module Version `1.1.4`

Everything works fine on my end.